# Zend Framework: The requested URL /my/path was not found on this server

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-routing

I am total new to Zend Framework.

I wrote a simple web service that return mock XML data with Zend Framework, with module structure like this:

```
AppName
    application
        configs
            application.ini
        modules
            default
                .....
            api
                controller
                    CatalogController.php
                view
        library
        public
            .htaccess
            index.php
        tests
```

In localhost (windows 7), these are working :

http://localhost

http://localhost/api/catalog

http://localhost/default

in my production server (linux), I get '404 file not found' from:

http://107.22.255.126/api/catalog

http://107.22.255.126/default

but this is working

http://107.22.255.126

I host it in Amazon Web Services.

Here is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Here is my application.ini

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
//resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] = "default"
resources.modules[] = "api"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts"
resources.layout.layout = master

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Here is my Bootstrap.php

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{

    protected function _initRoutes()
    {
        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $router = $front->getRouter();
        $restRoute = new Zend_Rest_Route($front, array(), array('api'));
        $router->addRoute('api', $restRoute);
    }

}

?>
```

I had run out of idea. I suspect this is something related with router in bootstraper, but can't find any solution.

Comment: Is the Apache error log saying anything?  When running in development mode, does Zend show any errors?

Comment: This is the access log: 


113.210.125.93 - - [04/Dec/2011:08:59:44 +0000] "GET /api/catalog HTTP/1.1" 404 289 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.121 Safari/535.2"


This is the error log:


[Sun Dec 04 09:16:35 2011] [error] [client 113.210.125.93] File does not exist: /var/www/html/TestMVC/public/Api

Comment: Can you post here specifiaction of production hosting? PHP version, web server etd. If prodution server use nginx the .htaccess file will not work. Access log shows that there was a request for ..public/Api but this should be public/index.php

Comment: Ah, looks like the rewrite rule isn't happening then.  Apache is looking for the actual file, and it's not being passed off to the router.  Try either making sure .htaccess are enabled in that directory, or just put the rewrite rule in the virtual host (or somewhere in the apache config).

Comment: @NorbertOrzechowicz you can view my phpInfo() at http://107.22.255.126/

Comment: @Corbin I had enabled .htaccess at my httpd.conf, and restart the Apache. Still the same.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Finally, the problem is because httpd.conf disable .htaccess on the directory. I added AllowOverride All to it under VirtualHost, and it works.

like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "var/www/html/TestMVC/public"

    <Directory "var/www/html/TestMVC/public">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Credit to @Corbin in the question's comment.

Comment: In my case wasn't necessary to include the Directory inside the VirtualHost. Just make sure there is one clear <Directory> tag with these instructions and reboot the server.

Comment: I was near to pull my hair. Thanks for saving my hair :)

Answer (score 5):

I had this kind of problem on  Ubuntu.
I went to apache2.conf and set one directory as below:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

The most important point is: AllowOverride All

Remember to set your apache configuration:
sudo a2enmod rewrite

Then is should work.

Answer (score 1):

yeap the solutions is::   http://www.phpcloud.com/help/adding-rewrite-rules-to-your-application

In step 3, I didn't mention but we didn't copy the default Elefant .htaccess file into our public folder. Instead, we're going to use the one provided by Zend in the PHPCloud documentation. Create a public/.htaccess file with the following contents:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
php_flag zend_codetracing.trace_enable on
php_flag zend_codetracing.always_dump on
```